# Lexical or Preprocessor issue when trying to archive project using the v2 BoxSDK

Tags: box-api

We're using the new v2 BoxSDK, and followed the steps on the github repo to integrate it as a subproject. Everything builds and runs fine, but we can't archive the project. We get the error:

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'BoxSDK/BoxSDK.h' file not found

I've tried several combinations of setting User Header Search Paths, but can't seem to find anything that works. It looks like the header files are being put in:

"IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include"

Has anyone had any luck getting the v2 BoxSDK working in an app when archiving?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally worked it out. You have to add the following entry to your **Header Search Paths**:

```
"$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/../UninstalledProducts/include"
```

Make sure you have the quotes in there.

Comment: I also had to turn on "Always Search User Paths"

Answer (score 4):

Add "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" to your header search path.

Answer (score 3):

On XCode 7.1 following **Header Search Path** worked for me for the Release Build

`$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/../UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/include`